# 'create' is misspelled or not recognized by the system on az ml dataset create

Tags: azure, azure-cli, azure-machine-learning-service, azuremlsdk

I'm trying to create a dataset on my azure ML workspace from a GitHub action

I've created a datastore and uploaded data to that datastore
when I try to create a dataset using the cli, I get this error:

`'create' is misspelled or not recognized by the system.`

this is the command i use:

```
> az ml dataset create 
          -n insurance_dataset 
          --resource-group rg-name 
          --workspace-name ml-ws-name 
          -p 'file:azureml/datastore/$(az ml datastore show-default -w ml-ws-name -g rg-name --query name -o tsv)/insurance/insurance.csv'
```

any idea what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried upgrading `Az CLI` to the latest version? [az ml : 'ml' is misspelled or not recognized by the system](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/21390),  [How to update the Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/update-azure-cli) and [az ml dataset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ml/dataset?view=azure-cli-latest#az-ml-dataset-create:~:text=This%20reference%20is%20part%20of%20the%20ml%20extension%20for%20the%20Azure%20CLI%20(version%202.15.0%20or%20higher))

Comment: @DeepDave-MT i tried, and now i get another error 
Error loading command module 'serviceconnector': cannot import name 'transform_validation_result' from 'azure.cli.command_modules.serviceconnector._transformers' (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI2\lib\site-packages\azure\cli\command_modules\serviceconnector\_transformers.pyc)
Error loading command module 'sqlvm': No module named 'azure.cli.command_modules.sqlvm._assessment_data_source'
'create' is misspelled or not recognized by the system.

Comment: Are these helpful? [After updating Azure CLI is broken](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/11357), [Error loading command modules](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/15517) and [Azure CLI ML Error - Error loading command module 'ml'](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3cd9250a-4fec-49ee-821a-629b75e72efe/azure-cli-ml-error-error-loading-command-module-ml?forum=MachineLearning)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

in my case, the issue was solved by upgrading the ml extension to `azure-cli-ml v2`

Remove any existing installation of the of `ml` extension and also the CLI v1 `azure-cli-ml` extension:

```
az extension remove -n azure-cli-ml
az extension remove -n ml
```

Now, install the ml extension:

```
az extension add -n ml -y
```

which still doesn't explain why the `create` command wasn't recognized, but the v2 behavior works fine for me.