# azure cli not recognizing the following command az ml data create -f <file-name>.yml

Tags: azure, yaml, azure-cli, azure-machine-learning-service, azuremlsdk

got a folder called data-asset which contains a yaml file with the following

```
type: uri_folder
name: <name_of_data>
description: <description goes here>
path: <path>
```

In a pipeline am referencing this using azure cli inline script using the following command az ml data create -f .yml but getting error

full error-D:\a\1\s\ETL\data-asset>az ml data create -f data-asset.yml
ERROR: 'ml' is misspelled or not recognized by the system.

Examples from AI knowledge base:
az extension add --name anextension
Add extension by name

trying to implement this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-create-register-data-assets?tabs=CLI

how can a resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the workaround you can follow to resolve the above issue;

Based on this [***GitHub issue***](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/21390#issuecomment-1161782243) as suggested by @*adba-msft* .

> **Please make sure that you have upgraded your azure cli to latest and**
> **Azure CLI ML extension v2 is being used.**

To check and upgrade the cli we can use the below `cmdlts`:

```
az version

az upgrade
```

[image]

For more information please refer this similar [***SO THREAD|'create' is misspelled or not recognized by the system on az ml dataset create***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73110661/create-is-misspelled-or-not-recognized-by-the-system-on-az-ml-dataset-create) .

I did observe the same issue after trying the aforementioned suggestion by @*Dor Lugasi-Gal* it works for me with (in my case `az ml -h`) after installed the extension with  `az extension add -n ml -y` can able to get the result of `az ml -h` without any error.

***SCREENSHOT FOR REFERENCE:-***

[image]